# Different types of Subway sandwiches

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose you are ordering a Subway sandwich for your friend. You are to
pick $1$ type of bread out of $5$, $1$ type of meat out of $7$, $2$ types of vegetables out of $8$, and $1$ types of sauce out of $8$. However, your friend has some specific preference: $(1)$ pickles
do not go with onions, and $(2)$ teriyaki chicken do not go with BBQ sauce. How many
different types of Subway sandwich you can order for your friend?

My attempt is below:

Case $1$ (Teriyaki + BBQ): $5*^8C_2$

Case $2$ (Pickles + Onions): $5*7*8$

Therefore,

$(5*7*^8C_2*8)-(5*^8C_2)-(5*7*8)+^5C_1=7425$

I added the $^5C_1$ at the end because I felt that the case of Teriyaki + BBQ + Pickles + Onions are included in both Case $1$ and $2$, which means I am actually subtracting the same case twice. There is hence a need for me to add that one case back at the end. Can someone please tell me if my rationale correct?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee oh sorry, I entered the wrong numbers! will correct it now.

Comment: Your work is correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks for verifying it for me! (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now correct. ( mostly answering to get it off the unanswered queue)